# Elasticsearch search body from URL search

Tags: elasticsearch

If I do a search directly to elasticsearch in a browser, such as:

http://localhost:9200/mydocs/_search?q=Awesome%20Search

What does the search body data actually look like? Is it doing a `multi_match` and including all fields?  I've tried writing a `multi_match` including all the fields and I get different results from doing it right in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?q=....` is not a `multi_match` query, this is [URI query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) and it's using [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

So your search is "translated" to:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Awesome Search"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `multi_match` query as request body like this

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_search?pretty=true' -d '{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"keyword","fields":["field1","field2"]}}}'
```